# Homebrew installation of git won't take precedence over system version (in /usr/bin/)

Tags: macos, git, path, package-management, homebrew

OS X (or Xcode) comes bundled with git 1.7.something, but after `brew install git` (1.8.0), `which git` keeps returning the old `/usr/bin/git`.

This is what I get when I echo $PATH right now:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Shouldn't Homebrew stuff take precedence?

Also, I've no idea where that `usr/local/git/bin` comes from at the end.

Comment: Have you verified that git is actually in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: yep. `ls /usr/local/bin` shows `git` is there. Brew also confirms that it's installed. I even ran the git uninstaller (both by `brew uninstall` and using the one that comes with the official git download) and redid `brew install git`. I keep getting `which git = = /usr/bin/git"`.

Comment: Run `which -a git` to see if it's finding it at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it. The answer is in your question; brew installs git to `/usr/local/git/bin` (not `/usr/local/bin`) but since that's after `/usr/bin` in your path, you get that one first. My comment for `which -a git` should have pointed you in this direction.

Comment: Run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/git` too. I bet it is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: Oh, and `/usr/local/git/bin` appears to be where the official installer puts it too.

Comment: You should look at `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d` as well.

Comment: here's an interesting turn of events: `which -a git` returns `/usr/local/bin/git; /usr/bin/git; /usr/local/bin/git`. So I renamed the old git `usr/bin/git_old` and got it out of the way. Now `git --version` returns 1.8, proving that brew did install git successfully. -- Again, I renamed `/usr/bin/git` to its original name... and suddenly it's working properly! I don't know why or how, but renaming `/usr/bin/git` and running git once seems to have solved the problem. Who knows what the root of the problem was. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: That's ... odd. Glad you're up and running now at least.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this issue.

After installing git through homebrew, if you run `brew doctor` then it will warn you that, as Joe mentioned above, the system is running the old git because its install location comes first.

But, in the same warning, homebrew gives the code to fix it:

```
$ echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s been part of my Unix habits to have a `~/bin` directory which I put at the start of my `PATH`. This is one of the first bits in my `.bashrc`:

```
case ":$PATH:" in
  *:$HOME/bin:*) ;;     # do nothing if $PATH already contains $HOME/bin
  *) PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH ;;  # in every other case, add it to the front
esac
```

With that in place, then selectively making just the Homebrew-managed `git` take precedence over the system version (instead of *every* Homebrew-managed binary), and just for your shell sessions (instead of *all* programs started from anywhere, including GUI programs), is as simple as symlinking it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/git ~/bin/git
```